# Formatting a paragraph indentation

Tags: indentation

I am using TeXStudio. Can I please ask how to apply the hanging indentation to a paragraph?
For an example,

Step 1. I am using TeXStudio to write a thesis.

The second line wants to be aligned up with the work 'I am using TeXstudio' instead of aligning up with 'Step 1'. Could someone help me solve this problem? Or give me some links to look at. 
Many thanks,

Comment: If you have another step, you can use `enumerate` environment making `\item[Step 1]` manually. Also, you can use `enumitem` package with `enumerate` environment https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem

Answer (score 3):

You can use a list; using the [`enumitem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package you can easily define a dedicated list (based on `enumerate`) producing the desired formatting:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{Steps}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[Steps,1]{label=Step~\arabic*.,leftmargin=*}

\begin{document}

Some test text and some more text and some more text and some more text and some more text and some more text and some more text
\begin{Steps}
\item Some test text and some more text and some more text and some more text and some more text and some more text and some more text
\item Some test text and some more text and some more text and some more text and some more text and some more text and some more text
\end{Steps}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please educate me as to how to get the correct format of the \newlist options such as leftmargin and indenting-- please see my question at  https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/515313/197451  and   https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/514903/197451    ---I read the enumerate package but could not find anything